# SQL Server computed column from another table column and current year

Tags: sql-server

I have two table named `Department` and `StudentRegister`.

In `Department` table there are three columns `DepartmentId`, `DepartmentCode`, and `DepartmentName`.

In `StudentRegister` table I have a column `StudentRegNo` of type `varchar`.
I have an asp.net mvc UI like this

[image]

In the department dropdown I have data like `CSE`, `EEE`, `ECE`, `URP`, `BBA`. I want `StudentRegister` as a computed column which generate value like `DepartmentCode-current year-XXX`.

For example:

```
CSE-2012-001, CSE-2012-002, EEE-2012-001, EEE-2013-001, CSE-2013-001, 
BBA-2015-001, BBA-2015-002, BBA-2015-003.
```

How can I do this? Please help.

Comment: This spans multiple tables. I think you need a view. Much of the info you posted is not relevant to answering the question while missing some of the  details that would be helpful.

Comment: And you said "computed column" but I think you actually want to store it since the year would change later. The expression should be almost trivial but you'll need to get to the point of actually doing an `insert` before we can really help much.

Comment: I would suggest that adding value to StudentRegNo is a bad idea. What happens when somebody accidentally chooses the wrong department for a given student? You have to update the StudentRegNo. This in itself isn't horrible but what all the other tables that use that value? You are violating 1NF by storing more than 1 piece of information in a single tuple.